# Rails Not Dividing Variables Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to do some ill-advised on-page ERB to calculate the value for a progress bar.

I have `@total_completed_lessons` and `@total_course_lessons` (which I know don't need `@` signs, but I'm still troubleshooting...).  These populate correctly.

However, when I try to divide them it comes out to zero:
`@total_completed_lessons / @total_course_lessons`

What is going on?  How is math not math-ing?

Here's a screenshot to show how I'm doing things.  (The 'd' is just to get the error screen to pop up so I can play with variables real-time.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It results in zero because you have to provide floats. This should work:

```
@total_course_lessons = @course_lesson_ids.count.to_f
@total_completed_lessons = @completed_lessons.count.to_f
percent = @total_completed_lessons / @total_course_lessons * 100
```

Comment: Could be simplified with just...`percent = @total_completed_lessons / @total_course_lessons.to_f * 100`...typically the denominator is the only value that is converted to a float in order to avoid truncation

Comment: Thank you!   I didn't see that it was rounding to 0 as opposed to just printing 0.  Now that I remember about integers vs floats this makes sense!